# validating only itunes app store and play store url in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am having a simple problem that is to validating url using ruby on rails technology.There are alot of solution for validating url but none works for me.As i want to allow only play store and app store url to save in database.

Say i have a play store app link.
here is my model:

```
class AppStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :custom

  private
  def custom
    if self.url_name.match /paly.google.com|itunes.apple.com/
    else
      self.errors.add(:url_name, 'must be app store url or paly store url')
    end
  end
end
```

Now the is when i enter url like "http://play.google.com" also the full url of the app then the validation is failling.
A sample url would be like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip

Please help me to solve this problem as.I am new to rails technology.
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
class AppStore < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_STORES = ['play.google.com', 'itunes.apple.com']

  validate :store_url_format

private

  def store_url_format
    unless VALID_STORES.any? { |host| url_name.includes?(host) }
      errors.add(:url_name, 'must be an AppStore or a PlayStore url')
    end
  end
end
```